# windows 2016 preventing Live Migration

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2016, failovercluster, live-migration

We have 2 Nodes in our cluster network and all hardwares have same specifications.
While am doing Live Migration am getting below error.

**Live migration of 'Virtual Machine TEST_SERVER_1' failed.

Virtual machine migration operation for 'TEST_SERVER_1' failed at migration destination 'ClusterNode2'. (Virtual machine ID CECBEFEC-48E1-4B18-94A0-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX)

The virtual machine 'TEST_SERVER_1' is using processor-specific features not supported on physical computer 'ClusterNode2'. 
To allow for migration of this virtual machine to physical computers with different processors, 
modify the virtual machine settings to limit the processor features used by the virtual machine.
 (Virtual machine ID CECBEFEC-48E1-4B18-94A0-XXXXXXXXXXXX)**

I have CSVFS network path from SAN storage and connected with fibercables.

Answer (score 2):

Settings > Processor > Compatibility: Migrate to a physical computer with a different processor version.

Comment: To follow on from this, even if you ordered 2 identical servers from the same vendor, it's not impossible that they have different BIOS/UEFI firmware loaded, settings enabled, etc. and this can make a difference.